# Shortcut for Right Click>Import from iPhone or iPad>Take Photo

Tags: macos, shortcuts, context-menu, macos-catalina

I'm using a lot of Take Photo with my iPhone (10-20 times a day) and would love to be able to do it with a single click on the keyboard like I do for other things with Karabiner but I'm unable to find a workaround.

So from Desktop I'd like to access automatically Context Menu>Import from iPhone or iPad>Take Photo

Any suggestions?

Thanks